# Rendering an already-loaded mesh using qt3d

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I have code which generates a mesh, i.e., as a `N x 3` array of doubles `V` of the 3D points and another `M x 3` array of integers `F` of the triangles. How can I render this mesh via qt3d (note the mesh is generated and hence not loaded from a file)? The task is so basic that it seems it should be straightforward but it seems qt3d is highly underdocumented.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this. You need to create your own `QGeometryRenderer`, `QGeometry`, `QBuffer`, and `QAttribute` instances to render custom geometry. I will try and respond a bit later with details on how to do this.

Comment: @ajshort - thanks! So considering this is undocumented as far as I can tell, and also if the code itself would be kinda cumbersome (sounds almost more cumbersome than directly using OPENGL), then what are the upsides of using qt3d?

Answer (score 0):

The Qt3D sources provide an example of how to do it for a simple cube:
qt3d\src\extras\geometries\qcuboidgeometry.cpp/.h
qt3d\src\extras\geometries\qcuboidmesh.cpp/.h
You can probably adapt it to your use case.